# Запрет символов + - . , в input React

Tags: reactjs, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста есть код:

```
const [day, setDay] = useState("");
    
<Input
    type="number"
    value={day}
    onChange={(e) => setDay(+e.target.value)}
    placeholder="1" 
/>
```

Как сделать что бы при вводе + - и точка заменялись на пустой символ

Comment: `setDay(+e.target.value.replace(/[+.\-]/g, ''))`

Comment: Не, так не работает, вводится всё ровно любой символ почему то

Comment: `setDay(Number(e.target.value.replace(/[+.\-]/g, '')))` Все ломал +

Comment: Всё ровно не корректно, заменяем только точку, а + и - пропускает, и если поставить +23.123 то тоже точку не заменит

Comment: Что то вы не то делаете или не так как указано. [Тестировал тут](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-feather-p4hl2u?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решения работает, просто надо было type number убрать ```setSumma(Number(e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')))}``` сделал так, а то выбивало в NaN если поставить равно или букву e

Comment: @UsbFan Вот тут есть ответ на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412002/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-input-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8/1412022#1412022